# Where is bar-code product attribute column in database?

Tags: magento2, barcode

[image]

Hi, I make a dump of my database than search for the value of barcode in my sql file but it doesn't give me any record , i want to know in my database in which table barcode number is saving ? please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all Barcode is not a default product attribute of magento 2 CE and EE.**

**So this Barcode attribute is created by some one from backend or created by any third party extension**

**As magento have EAV structure to store its value so first we need to identify Barcode is which data type of attribute**

So you can find Barcode name in  **eav_attribute** table

And you can found its entry in **any of one table among below 3** as its based on data type which is defined by attribute creator.

**catalog_product_entity_int**

**catalog_product_entity_text**

**catalog_product_entity_varchar**

Comment: yes i found it in (SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar`) , i succesfully obtained all barcodes of products whose prices were 1 using this query : (SELECT A.entity_id , A.price , B.value
from catalog_product_index_price As A 
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar as B on A.entity_id = B.entity_id 
where A.price=1 ;) ..............and thanks alot for your brief help , <3

Comment: @HamzaMustafa - Happy to help , Keep helping :)