# Where is the Barcode Attribute Stored in the Database

Tags: magento2, database

I want to run some queries for reporting purposes and need to display the barcode of each product, but I cannot find it.

I have followed the answer on the following post but I still cannot get the barcode.

[Where is bar-code product attribute column in database?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/where-is-bar-code-product-attribute-column-in-database)

I tried looking in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table but did not find anything useful and the data filled in

```
catalog_product_entity_int

catalog_product_entity_text

catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

tables did not seem to help either.

Could it be stored on some other table or has there been a problem with the product immigration?

Many thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You are on correct way, but you need to check `eav_attribute` table.

- The table `eav_attribute` contains information about all attributes
- The table `catalog_eav_attribute` contains extended attribute properties applicable for catalog

Try to find your barcode attribute by `attribute_code` in `eav_attribute` and after you can find `attribute_id` for value table and type in `backend_type`.

Comment: After I find the attribute_id how would I query for it to show when searching for a specific product? (It might be a fairly simple answer but I don't really know SQL that well)